# Как черно-белые эмодзи перевести в цветные?

Tags: php, html, mysql

Поставил кодировку на mysql utf8mb4.
Эмодзи выводятся, но все черно-белые. Подскажите, что нужно добавить на сайт , чтобы они стали цветными ?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: БД не раскрашивает ваши эмодзи. Какую записываете - такую и выводит.

Comment: добавьте CSS что ли

Comment: Наличие или отсутствие раскраски зависит не от mysql, а от шрифта, которым рисуются символы

Comment: @netflix взываем к тебе

Comment: А эти эмодзи на каком шрифте ? кодировку их посмотрите .